# Which files do i save in each of the folders in the file manager for a website?

Tags: webserver, website, godaddy

I have a godaddy.com hosting and domain, in file manager there are the folders

etc

logs

mail

public_ftp

public_html

tmp

What is each of this folders supposed to store and do they have any other differences?, like being / not being accessible, etc?

Comment: Well, looking at the folder names, I'm guessing the prefix "public" probably means those are the folders that are mostly accessible and meant for public webpage stuff. Based on this question though, I'd HIGHLY recommend that you look into the documentation GoDaddy has for first-time website builders and read it thoroughly and carefully. Running a website is fun, but it's also no joke, and if you're not aware or doing things right, you could quickly become part of the problems on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard view of most web hosting setups:

- logs - this is where you will find log files with informatiion about
  your web site user access
- mail - self explanatory :-)
- public_ftp - this is where you place files that you want others to
  access via the ftp protocol - for most web site owners this will not
  be used
- public_html - this is where you place your website files (index.html 
  as a minimum) with subfolder and structure for images, css etc.
  Essentialy anything that you place here can be accessed via a browser
  from anywhere
- tmp - temporary folder